# How to separate list items in python on the basis of something common?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Suppose there is a list

```
primary_list=['f1', 'f2', 'f3', 't1.txt', 't2.txt', 't3.txt', 't4.txt', 't5.txt']
```

now If I waned to separate elements with ".txt " to get into a new separate list how can I do that?

Comment: Do you want to modify this list to remove items not required, or do you want a new list with just the things you want?

Comment: @quamrana Ya you can say that I want to modify this list by removing element I don't want those elements are those which don't have any extension with them.

Comment: no it doesn't answer  my question the answer below is what I was looking for.

Comment: Ok, but the question I linked to was primarily answered with list comprehensions which created new lists. Very few modified the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use list comprehension with string split method -

```
new_list_without_txt = [item for item in primary_list if '.txt' not in item ]
new_list_with_txt = [item for item in primary_list if '.txt' in item ]
print(new_list_without_txt)
print(new_list_with_txt)
```

output--

```
['f1', 'f2', 'f3']
['t1.txt', 't2.txt', 't3.txt', 't4.txt', 't5.txt']
```

```
primary_list=['f1', 'f2', 'f3', 't1.txt', 't2.txt', 't3.txt', 't4.txt', 't5.txt']
new_list = [item.split('.txt')[0] if '.txt' in item else item for item in primary_list]
print(new_list)
```

output -

```
['f1', 'f2', 'f3', 't1', 't2', 't3', 't4', 't5']
```

Answer (score 2):

As shown in Nk03's answer and quamrana's comment, you can use list comprehension to create a new list. To add to this, if you would like to filter specifically a suffix, use the endswith() method. Otherwise, items will get filtered out, even if .txt happens to appear somewhere else in the text.

```
primary_list=['f1', 'f2', 'f3', 't1.txt', 't2.txt', 't3.txt', 't4.txt', 't5.txt']
new_list = [item for item in primary_list if not item.endswith('.txt')]
new_list_two = [item for item in primary_list if item.endswith('.txt')]
print(new_list)
print(new_list_two)
```

Output:

```
['f1', 'f2', 'f3']
['t1.txt', 't2.txt', 't3.txt', 't4.txt', 't5.txt']
```